# How to express JSON-LD of original content?

Tags: html, json-ld

How to express semantic of *original content* (**not** a set of separated values)  by JSON-LD **instead** Microdata?

Suppose this fragment of HTML+Microdata into the HTML `<body>`:

```
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">George Bush</span>, the
  <span itemprop="disambiguatingDescription">44th President of the USA</span>.
</p>
```

How to convert its Microdata into JSON-LD?

---

Suppose also that we can use many IDs:

```
<p>
  <span id="person1-name">George Bush</span>, the
  <span id="person1-rule">44th President of the USA</span>.
</p>
```

... So I am imagining to add into the HTML `<head>` something as:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": { "@id": "#person1-name" },
  "disambiguatingDescription": { "@id": "#person1-rule" }
}
</script>
```

Is it? That is, any "Web Semantic interpreter" tool will accept this kind of relative intralink reference, or it is not for practical use (only theoretic) in nowadays?

Comment: Trying to discuss at https://github.com/w3c/json-ld-syntax/issues/382

Answer (score 2):

It's only possible via the cssSelector or xpath properties which are currently only available in a WebPageElement or the SpeakableSpecification. So no use for your scenario.

If you wanted to combine microdata and json-ld then you would use the itemid in microdata to match the @id in json-ld. However Google does not support that.

Comment: And about the [Web Annotation Data Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/), we can use it in this context?

Comment: Interesting read. I'm not sure if it would be possible to use an Annotation in the scenario you showed. How would it be connected to a property?

Comment: Hi Tony, I am supposing that we can use both, [xpath](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/#xpath-selector) and [cssSelector](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/#css-selector) in the case of ID. For generic case, of HTML5 content, the cssSelector is the best choice.

Comment: Hi Tony, no news in 2023?  see  bounty!

Answer (score 2):

At the Google Search Central Live event in Zurich a few months ago Google announced support for merging different formats like Microdata and JSON-LD.

This means you can now mark up parts of your information via microdata, and parts in JSON-LD and merge them via an id.

I Xed about it before the event (they rolled it out just before):

https://twitter.com/TonyMcCreath/status/1715047852303368597

Comment: Sorry Tony, I was on holiday and the bounty expired. Thank you very much for your answer!